# How to Solve KeyError in View Django

Tags: python, django

When I attempt to render a view, I am getting an error message 'KeyError at /manifest'.  I am working with sessions for the first time so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. I'm trying to achieve passing a field 'reference' from the `edit_manifest_frombrowse` view to the `manifest` view using sessions. Could someone explain to me what is prompting this error and why I might fix it? Code and full traceback below:

views.py

```
def edit_manifest_frombrowse(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Manifests, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data["reference"]
        return redirect('manifest')


    else:
        form = CreateManifestForm(instance=item)

        return render(request, 'edit_manifest_frombrowse.html', {'form': form})


def manifest(request):
    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":

        ...


    reference_id = request.session.pop('reference', None)
    data = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference_id)
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={

         'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id),

         })
    total_cases = Manifests.objects.filter(reference__reference=reference_id).aggregate(Sum('cases'))

    context = {
    'reference_id': reference_id,
    'form': form,
    'data': data,
    'total_cases': total_cases['cases__sum'],

     }

    return render(request, 'manifest_readonly.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'product_name', 'count', 'CNF', 'FOB')
```

models.py

```
#form which I am trying to submit
class Manifests(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(Orders)

#just showing so you can see what the FK reference
class Orders(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

FULL TRACEBACK

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'bootstrap_modal_forms',
 'smart_selects',
 'unit']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/andrews/Desktop/WBU/web_unit/unit/views.py" in manifest
  325.     reference_id = request.session.pop('reference')

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in pop
  73.         return self._session.pop(key, *args)

Exception Type: KeyError at /manifest
Exception Value: 'reference'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because that's the behavior of pop method.

> **pop(key[, default])**: If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default. If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

So to solve it you could use fallback to get rid of this error. E.g:

```
reference_id = request.session.pop("reference", None)
```

There is an issue with your logic might be the root cause which lead you to this error.

```
if form.is_valid():
    request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data["reference"]
return redirect('manifest')
```

In case your form is invalid then you won't have `reference` on session variable so that you're unable to get it in `manifest` view. So try to redirect to another view or try this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Do other stuff
    request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data["reference"]
else:
    # Do other stuff
    request.session["reference"] = ""
return redirect('manifest')
```

There is another issue with your form when you want to initiate with a queryset. It will try to parse your Orders queryset to JSON-like data for your form and that will prompt an error. You should try to create alternative field for `reference` field and set queryset for that field on **init** method like so:

```
# forms.py
class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reference = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Orders.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'product_name', 'count', 'CNF', 'FOB')

    def __init__(self, reference, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateManifestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['reference'].queryset = reference
```

Then you can initiate your form like this:

```
form = CreateManifestForm(reference=Orders.objects.filter(reference=reference_id))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: that did indeed remove the error,  but really my problem here is that I need the ```None```.  The implicatation of needing that is that ```request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data["reference"]``` isn't assigning anything right? I think this is really where my problem is.  That SHOULD be assigning a value - not be empty.  Do you see any reason why that might not be working?

Comment: have you debug it? too make sure that your form is valid?

Comment: Well, it should be: `request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data['reference']` if it's like your comment, then the interpreter will consider `form.cleaned_data('reference')` as you want to call a function instead of access dictionary value.

Comment: yeah I just realized that - this is really leading down a wormhole - now that I've corrected it gives a new TypeError that "<Orders: 219003> is not JSON serializable" and I again don't know how to make that so. You've been very helpful

Comment: request.session["reference"] = ' '   ---  Does this create an error? (if u put it in the "else" field)

Comment: @Jay no it doesn't seem to assuming you mean to put it just under ```else:```

Comment: @Jay `else` block is just like a fallback to make sure session include `reference` key.
@GXM100, I believe that error comes up after this `reference_id = request.session.pop('reference')` so that I'm unable to see it because it's not on your question.

Comment: @ToanQuocho Yeah, I think you're right. But could a remedy for this error simply be not including the "Else" field? Or setting it as '' instead of None?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I've edited the ```manifest``` view above to show the rest of that

Comment: (I'm guessing [and I'm guessing b/c I'm drunk lol] that somewhere in your models 'None' isn't an option. Thus, you have to make it one, or use '' instead ...

Comment: @Jay, make sense to me. updating

Comment: I believe this line create that error: `'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id),` it's trying to parse the data type to match with the form field (`reference` field). If you could provide your model with only `reference` field in it. That might help a lot.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I've updated above to show that in the original question

Comment: @ToanQuocHo it's hard to believe that this could possibly have led to another error but something about that form change I assume has now given me "Orders object has no attriubte 'all' ".  I have other views which reference Orders.objects.all().  I assume that form change has caused an error with those views now.

Comment: Make sure that's no where have this code `Orders.all()`, follow the error message I think that there're some where the code is like that. Actually you now it should be `Orders.objects.all()`. You could try to find that code on your project because maybe somebody else added that by mistake. @GXM100

Comment: @ToanQuocHo yeah it's so close to working - seemingly changing ```form = CreateManifestForm(reference=Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id))``` to ```form = CreateManifestForm(reference=Orders.objects.filter(reference=reference_id))``` solved that.  But the issue now is that the reference field is not actually initializing, it is just an empty value in the dropdown with the only option being the correct ```reference```

Comment: Oh I missed that point, `get` won't return a queryset for you. Can you make sure that `Orders.objects.filter(reference=reference_id)` have data?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo yeah it has data. I mean the dropdown has a value in it, and it’s the correct one, it just isn’t set as the initial value. The user has to select it from a list of one item

Comment: In below of ‘self.fields[“reference”].query = ...’, try to put this line: ‘self.fields[“reference”].initial = 0’. There might be a better solution and I will come up with that soon, will update the answer right after that. @GXM100

Comment: Do you mean to replace that line? Or to add ...initial = 0 underneath of it? Really thank you for your help